# Recommended Literature for creating Factor Mimicking Portfolios

Tags: modern-portfolio-theory, factor-models, asset-pricing

Is there a textbook that contains the basics for creating Factor Mimicking Portfolios? Although there is a lot of peer-reviewed literature on this, I cannot find textbooks on Asset Pricing that explain in "plain words" how to create Factor Mimicking Portfolios.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty good explanation is in Schweser CFA Study Notes for CFA level III. Books 3 and 5, at least from 2009, if I remember right. See also Tsay R.S. Analysis of Financial Time Series (Wiley Series in Probability and Statistics). // 2010.  - good example with implementation in R.